# T2A does not have some font sizes

Tags: fontsize, font-encodings, cyrillic

Here is the minimal code. I need to use the encoding `T2A` for Cyrillic characters. But the problem is that some font sizes are not available. I discovered that I should use also `T1` after `T2A`. But using `12pt` the section's heading does not appear. The example below show the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document} 
\chapter{Russian}
\section{title}    

foo
\end{document}
```

Here is the important part from `log` file.

```
{\cyrillictext \CYRG \cyrl \cyra \cyrv \cyra } 1.
! Font T2A/cmr/bx/n/17.28=labx1728 at 17.28pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.13 \section{title}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I get no error. Your TeX installation may be faulty.

Comment: @egreg, I edited.

Comment: No error either. You are missing the Cyrillic fonts from your TeX distribution, apparently. What distribution are you using?

Comment: @egreg, last weekend I installed TeXlive 2013 from iso dvd. I got from the website. Maybe some local fonts from my older TeXlive (2011) could be the problem? What else fonts do I need? Just today I updated everything using `tlmgr`.

Comment: Do you have something in your “personal tree”, that is in `~/texmf`?

Comment: I don't have this folder. I have only the hidden `.texlive2013` (also 2011) with a lot of subfolders.

Comment: Try renaming `.texlive2013`. Did you install a full TeX Live?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have `.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a` with a lot of `mf` files. For example, `labx1440.mf`. But not that number from the error log. I tried now to rename it and more errors have appeared: `! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`

Comment: The problem appears only when I load `babel` with Russian option.

Comment: I do get output but it does fail to find type1 fonts for all of the characters so that it generates some from .mf fonts on the first run. I don't know much about Cyrillic fonts but I'm not sure it should be trying to create .mf files to use, or is that normal?

Comment: @cfr, also the process is too slow.